# Phone number validation in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

I code for the phone number validation and it is working. The problem is the requirement for the phone number is not required but it asks to must put the phone number in the form.The form must be submitted with or without phone number field filled.
my code for phone no validation

```
'contact_no' => 'regex:/^[0][0-9]{9}$/',
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `'regex:/^(|[0][0-9]{9})$/',`

Comment: why ? I have no idea about laravel, but this regexp should work properly.
Only empty text or 10 digits started from 0

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, it is always encouraged to add an explanation explaining why/how it works to it.

Comment: The number validation is working but the problem is the form must submit with or without contact no field filled. in my form, I couldn't submit without fill this contact any field. i want to submit the form with or without fill the contact number field.the code for required is     'contact_no' => 'required|regex:/^[0][0-9]{9}$/',